# Calculate interval period between two non zero demands in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I've below data time series data - with the columns *Model*     *Month*    *Year*    *Quantity*, and I would like to create a column/new variable in a dataframe called *DemandInterval*(as shown below ) which calculates the **demand interval** between two non zero quantities using R code.

```
Model       Month    Year    Quantity   DemandInterval
    Model-A     7   2017    0           0
    Model-A     8   2017    1           1
    Model-A     9   2017    1           1
    Model-A     10  2017    1           1
    Model-A     11  2017    0           0
    Model-A     12  2017    0           0
    Model-A     1   2018    0           0
    Model-A     2   2018    0           0
    Model-A     3   2018    0           0
    Model-A     4   2018    1           6
    Model-A     5   2018    5           1
    Model-A     6   2018    0           0
    Model-A     7   2018    0           0
    Model-A     8   2018    0           0
    Model-A     9   2018    1           4
    Model-A     10  2018    0           0
    Model-A     11  2018    1           2
    Model-A     12  2018    0           0
    Model-A     1   2019    1           2
    Model-A     2   2019    1           1
    Model-A     3   2019    0           0
    Model-A     4   2019    0           0
    Model-A     5   2019    2           3
    Model-A     6   2019    0           0
    Model-A     7   2019    0           0
    Model-A     8   2019    1           3
    Model-A     9   2019    1           1
    Model-A     10  2019    0           0
    Model-A     11  2019    1           2
    Model-A     12  2019    1           1
    Model-A     1   2020    0           0
    Model-A     2   2020    0           0   
    Model-A     3   2020    1           3
    Model-A     4   2020    1           1
    Model-A     5   2020    3           1
    Model-A     6   2020    1           1
```

Will be glad if someone can help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution. It works by filtering out all the Quantity zero rows, then finding the interval between the remaining rows. This is then `left_join`ed back on to the original data frame. The numbers will all be correct, apart from those with Quantity 0, which will be `NA`. These are just changed to zeros eith an `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)

(df %>% left_join(
  df %>% filter(Quantity != 0) %>% 
  mutate(DemandInterval = c(1, diff(Year * 12 + Month))), by = names(df))) %>%
  mutate(DemandInterval = ifelse(is.na(DemandInterval), 0, DemandInterval))

#>      Model Month Year Quantity DemandInterval
#> 1  Model-A     7 2017        0              0
#> 2  Model-A     8 2017        1              1
#> 3  Model-A     9 2017        1              1
#> 4  Model-A    10 2017        1              1
#> 5  Model-A    11 2017        0              0
#> 6  Model-A    12 2017        0              0
#> 7  Model-A     1 2018        0              0
#> 8  Model-A     2 2018        0              0
#> 9  Model-A     3 2018        0              0
#> 10 Model-A     4 2018        1              6
#> 11 Model-A     5 2018        5              1
#> 12 Model-A     6 2018        0              0
#> 13 Model-A     7 2018        0              0
#> 14 Model-A     8 2018        0              0
#> 15 Model-A     9 2018        1              4
#> 16 Model-A    10 2018        0              0
#> 17 Model-A    11 2018        1              2
#> 18 Model-A    12 2018        0              0
#> 19 Model-A     1 2019        1              2
#> 20 Model-A     2 2019        1              1
#> 21 Model-A     3 2019        0              0
#> 22 Model-A     4 2019        0              0
#> 23 Model-A     5 2019        2              3
#> 24 Model-A     6 2019        0              0
#> 25 Model-A     7 2019        0              0
#> 26 Model-A     8 2019        1              3
#> 27 Model-A     9 2019        1              1
#> 28 Model-A    10 2019        0              0
#> 29 Model-A    11 2019        1              2
#> 30 Model-A    12 2019        1              1
#> 31 Model-A     1 2020        0              0
#> 32 Model-A     2 2020        0              0
#> 33 Model-A     3 2020        1              3
#> 34 Model-A     4 2020        1              1
#> 35 Model-A     5 2020        3              1
#> 36 Model-A     6 2020        1              1
```

Comment: Super, this works. Thanks a lot Allan for your help! This community rocks. :-) Plus your logic to use diff function for finding consecutive lags by doing (year*12)+month is awesome. Any guidance to learn such date time calculation please, because it is not occur intuitively to me.Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you @Gayatri - you are very welcome. There's no secret to this type of thing, it's just pattern recognition, trial and error and lots of practice! SO is great place to learn.

Comment: Sure, will keep doing and try to be active member here. Thank you again.